# array of structs and malloc [C]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a problem with this code. I want to code a program that has various personal info in an array. And I want 15 Arrays to be set up in one place in the memory (malloc).
Also the programm should output (printf) the personal info of one person on request (angestellter[0 - 14]).

The Code Errors I recive are the following:

> ```
> gcc ANGDB.c 
> ANGDB.c: In function ‘print_angestellter’:
> ANGDB.c:14:18: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>  nu = angestellter[x].nummer;
>                   ^
> ANGDB.c:15:18: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>  vn = angestellter[x].vorname;
>                   ^
> ANGDB.c:16:18: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>  nn = angestellter[x].nachname;
>                   ^
> ANGDB.c: In function ‘main’:
> ANGDB.c:25:13: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>  angestellter[0] -> nummer = 1;
>              ^
> ANGDB.c:26:13: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>  angestellter[0] -> vorname = "George";
>              ^
> ANGDB.c:27:13: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>  angestellter[0] -> nachname = "Washington";
> ```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct angestellter{
    int nummer;
    char vorname[50];
    char nachname[50];
}angestellter;

void print_angestellter(int x){
    int nu;
    char vn[50];
    char nn[50];
    nu = angestellter[x].nummer;
    vn = angestellter[x].vorname;
    nn = angestellter[x].nachname;
    printf("%d, %s, %s\n", nu, vn, nn);
}

int main(){
    struct angestellter **db = malloc(sizeof(angestellter)*15);
    angestellter[0] -> nummer = 1;
    angestellter[0] -> vorname = "George";
    angestellter[0] -> nachname = "Washington";
    print_angestellter(0);
}
```

Comment: `angestellter` is a single variable of type `struct angestellter`; you cannot use subscripting on it.

Comment: It looks like you are allocating memory and assigning it to a variable named db. Shouldn't you use db instead of angestellter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you're using `angestellter`, which is a single instance of `struct angestellter`, you should be using `db`, which is your dynamically allocated array.  You should also declare it as `struct angestellter *` instead of `struct angestellter **`.  This will also need to be passed to `print_angestellter`.

You also need to use `strcpy` to copy strings.  You can't directly assign a string to a character array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct angestellter{
    int nummer;
    char vorname[50];
    char nachname[50];
};

void print_angestellter(struct angestellter *db, int x){
    int nu;
    char vn[50];
    char nn[50];
    nu = db[x].nummer;
    strcpy(vn, db[x].vorname);     // use strcpy to copy strings
    strcpy(nn, db[x].nachname);
    printf("%d, %s, %s\n", nu, vn, nn);
}

int main(){
    struct angestellter *db = malloc(sizeof(struct angestellter)*15);
    db[0].nummer = 1;
    strcpy(db[0].vorname, "George");
    strcpy(db[0].nachname, "Washington");
    print_angestellter(db, 0);
}
```

Comment: `print_angestellter` could pass the struct members directly: `printf("%d, %s, %s\n", db[x].nummer, db[x].vorname, db[x].nachname);`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two issues. First of all, in your `print_angestellter()` function, you use the global `angestellter` struct, which is perfectly fine. However, it is a **struct**, not an array or pointer to memory. Therefore you cannot use the operator `[]`, hence the errors. It seems that you will have to redesign `print_angestellter()` or make `angestellter`an array of `struct angestellter`s. You also made a similar mistake in `main()`, doing `angestellter[0]` instead of `db[0]`. To fix this, I suggest adding a pointer argument to `print_angestellter()`, say making it `print_angestellter(int, struct *angestellter a)` and replacing `angestellter[0]` with `a[0]`.
You also use `=` to copy strings, but that copies the pointer addresses, **not** the contents of the string. Use `strcpy()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote "struct angestellter **db = malloc(sizeof(angestellter)*15);"means pointer of array,its ok,but you should use "db[0]->number" to replace "angestellter[0] -> nummer";The function "void print_angestellter()",you should add formal parameter"dp",when you use "malloc",don't forget use "free" to free the memory you apply；

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to visit [**How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to help you format your answer so that it is more readable with the code distinguishable from the general text, etc..